# show only one li item when sliding list items from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a text slider and I want to show only one li item per slide. The data in li items is being fetched from DB and inserted to DOM by JS. The problem right now is that all of the li items are showing while sliding, current elem shows at top. How I can make sure that only one li item shows per slide with css?

I tried to make the li items display: inline and float but it did not help.

```
#slider ul li{display: inline}
```

Here is the [website](http://5280.us/test-2/) where I am testing. Please help me understand how I can do this or what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the text in the main body that rotates, you can hide all but the first `li` with

```
#slider li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```